# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 'entityManagerFactory' as in classpath jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was getting the below error when running the springBoot Application initailly

"org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Coulenter code hered not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister".

Please find the below pom.xml of the project.

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.1.13.RELEASE
         
    
    com.petpeers
    projectdemo
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    projectdemo
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And As i was using the H2 database , here is the application.properties file.

As the error is due to the entities creation. please find the two entities created in the project : One is Pets and other one is PetUsers.

I have tried all the scenarioes which are appeared in the stack overflow, still i was not able to solve the problem.
please find the complete project in the link : https://github.com/kiranmahesh93/PetProject.

Comment: I think you need to remove hibernate-core and hibernate entity manager as they are included in spring boot starter data jpa

Comment: moskura, i have removed both the dependencies and tries, it is throwing the same exception

Comment: I am sorry but I have cloned your code and could not reproduce the problem
Can you update your code , that I can reproduce the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: moskura, is the code is working fine for you or it is getting some other error

Comment: All classes except Pets and SpringBootApplication are empty

Comment: Can you push the code?